# Are there any stats or guidelines for deities' stats?

Tags: dnd-5e, religions-and-deities

Earlier editions of D&D had rules for how powerful deities were if you were ever to fight one, including class levels, statblocks and special powers.

Does D&D 5th edition have any stats on deities, or rules on how powerful they are?

Comment: [Extremely close to a duplicate.](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/110625/15469)

Comment: Related: [stats for Asmodeus *et al.*](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/79232/23970), [how to kill a deity in 5e](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/61643/23970)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes - there is one.

[Rise of Tiamat](http://dnd.wizards.com/products/tabletop-games/rpg-products/rise-tiamat) states on p. 87 "Tiamat is a god" and gives statistics for her in the Appendix.

She is given a CR of 30 and the book says: "If she manifests through the portal
at full strength, she can demolish multiple 15th-level parties with ease."

Comment: Tiamat is a deity, no?

Comment: @DavidCoffron It was Tiamat's avatar, not a deity itself, if I recall correctly, so I'm supporting this answer.

Comment: @DavidCoffron AntiDrondert is correct.  I suspect that the down votes may represent not quite seeing the distinction between Tiamat and her avatar in the ToD/RoT published material.  Possibly a reaction to the brevity of the answer as well.

Comment: @Korvin From page 87 of Rise of Tiamat: "Tiamat the Dragon Queen is about to
burst bodily from her confinement in the Nine Hells and
enter the world." This is not an avatar

Comment: @DavidCoffron OK, I'll take a peek at my copy later and get back to you.  I was under the impression that, per FR Lore, the death of a god only happens at the hands of other gods or Ao, but I have a vague memory about something in Nethril that may oppose that ...

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how broad your definition of deities is, you might include the demon lords from Mordenkainen's Tome of Foes. Although their worshipers are comprised of pretty much only the most insane cults, they are worshiped, grant spells, abilities, etc. to their followers.

Their CR is in the 22+ range, but that doesn't include their Lair, which is where you'd need to kill them for them to stay dead.